# Style element to be left: x px of the page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div inside a div inside a div ... By default each comtainer moves elements more and more to the right.

I have a elements `"div.leftPanel"` that can be nested very deeply in but I want it to be 50px (for args sake) to the left of the document (where the body's left property would be) and not it's parent element. Some of it's containers need to have a position of absolute or relative.

Is there any way to do this with css? if not then javascript?

Comment: Does the parent of `div.leftPanel` have positioning other than static (the default)?

Comment: @Joseph: "Some of it's containers need to have a position of absolute or relative."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative margin to achieve this if you already know how far the nested div has been pushed out from the left of the body. Example:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left: 30px;">
    <div style="position:absolute; left: 30px;">
        <div style="position: relative; margin-left: -10px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it isn't set, you can always find out how far from using javascript and apply the margin dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `position: absolute;` and `left: 50px;` to `div.leftPanel`, and none of its parent elements have any position (`absolute` or `relative`), then the `50px` will be calculated from the left edge of the document.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the sentence where you said some of the parents had to have a position. Can you just move `div.leftPanel` out of the other `<div>`s entirely? Maybe just place it at the root of the document so its position will be calculated from the edge of the document.

Comment: If I could I wouldn't have much a question now, would I?